# VB.NET can not detect uncheck state of checkbox/radio in gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I am having a tough time debugging this weird issue (maybe it is weird because I am a PHP guy doing VB.NET stuffs for the first time)

I have a Gridview like below

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridViewID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="employee_id" DataSourceID="all_employee" >
    <Columns>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="employee_id" HeaderText="employee_id" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="employee_id" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="employee_name" HeaderText="employee_name" 
            SortExpression="employee_name" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <br />
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioPermission" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ItemStyle-CssClass="visibility" ShowHeader="false"
                            HeaderStyle-CssClass="visibility" >
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="visibility" />
        <ItemStyle CssClass="visibility" />
        </asp:CommandField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then I have a button to Save the information to database, it works very well with the saving part

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In MyGridViewID.Rows
        Dim radio_cp As RadioButtonList =    CType(row.Cells(7).FindControl("RadioPermission"), RadioButtonList)

        If radio_cp.SelectedValue = 1 Then
            ' BLOCK A: saving to the db if the radio is YES
        Else
            ' BLOCK B: deleting from the db if the radio is NO.
        End If

    Next
```

My issue:

1. When all radio set to NO for the first time I load the Gridview, I choose YES for some radio and click save, it works nicely.
2. Then the Gridview is refreshed and the changes reflected correctly in those radios.
3. Then I select NO for a radio which is currently set to YES and click Save again => radio_cp.SelectedValue is always return 1.
4. The issue is the same with Checkbox and Radio: I could not detect when the user uncheck checkbox/radio. I think the gridview hold the state of those checckbox/radio somewhere but I could not figure out
5. I tried with EnableViewState with no lucks, Googling a lot without lucks too.
6. I tried with OnCheckedChecked event but it did not work.

I could missing something here, could you help?

Thank you for all of your time!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work...
I've patched up a simple app based on your code and it works just fine.

I am not sure where exactly the problem is, is there something else that may affect the radiobuttonlist?

EDIT:

This will probably have no effect on your issue, but can you do this:

```
Dim radio_cp As RadioButtonList =    CType(row.FindControl("RadioPermission"), RadioButtonList)
```